# Host multiple site under IIS on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: iis

I have to host two site under same server. 
I have one IP address and a server with windows server 2012 R2.
How can i set iis to run two different site with same Ip.

tks all

Comment: You can use different port e.g. if default site is hosted on port 80 then other can be hosted on port 81.

Comment: I have to add a node to Site ?

Comment: Is first time i try this...could you provide a link with an example ? tks in any case

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: create 2 different websites with different ports (you can set the port in the "Bindings" section). In that case you could access them from a web browser using the pattern http://*DOMAIN*:*PORT* 
Option 2: create 1 website (you can use the default website) and create 2 different web applications in it.  In that case you could access your apps with the pattern http://*DOMAIN*:*PORT*/*APP_NAME* but if you put the site on port 80 then you dont need to specify the port for none of them.
 
If you are also the one who needs to maintain it, I would recommend you to take the course:
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/iis-for-developers
pluralsight are your friends